# Can JSP build a list of <option> elements to be inserted into multiple unique <select> tags?

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP file that builds out an object list to display task data and builds a  populated with several options the user can choose for each row of data. The problem is that any given user can have hundreds of rows which can take a significant amount of time to process. The code looks something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${user.taskList}" var="task" varStatus="stat">
    (print out task info and other inputs)
    ...
    <select id="taskStatus_${stat.index}">
        <c:forEach items="${applicationScope.task_status_list}" var="lkup">
        <option value="${lkup.lkupId}" cssStyle="font-size: 12px;">${lkup.lkupNme}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</c:forEach>
```

In an attempt to reduce the processing time I want to build the  list once and reuse it. I've unsuccessfully tried to do this with variations of the following code:

```
<c:set var="option_list" value="" />
<c:forEach items="${applicationScope.task_status_list}" var="lkup">
    <c:set var="option_list">
        ${option_list} <option value="${lkup.lkupId}" cssStyle="font-size: 12px;">${lkup.lkupNme}</option>
    </c:set>
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach items="${user.taskList}" var="task" varStatus="stat">
    (print out task info and other inputs)
    ...
    <select id="taskStatus_${stat.index}">
        ${option_list}
    </select>
</c:forEach>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or another solution I should look into?
Thanks in advance.